# Разделительный мягкий знак перед суффиксом "ск"

Tags: мягкий-знак

Почему в некоторых словах на стыке "р" и "ск" пишется мягкий знак, а в некоторых — опускается?

Примеры: *егерский, январский.*

Comment: Это не разделительный мягкий знак, а самый обычный, то есть он обозначает мягкость согласного. Разделительный знак обозначает звук Й между согласным и гласным: полью.

Answer (score 2):

Пишите по слуху, и у Вас всё получится: ***егерский, январский*** (звук Р твердый).

Звук Р  стоит **перед твердым согласным С**, который никаким образом  не может его смягчить   (нет взаимного влияния и фонетического изменения).

Позиция звука Р считается **сильной**, в этом случае звук обозначается буквой по слуху: ***январский, декабрьский.***

Или посмотрите правило в ПАС:

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=25#pp25

Примечание. В большинстве прилагательных с суффиксом -ск- согласные н и р перед суффиксом — твердые, поэтому ь в них не пишется, напр.: конский, казанский, тюменский, рыцарский, январский, егерский. Однако в следующих прилагательных эти согласные перед суффиксом -ск- мягкие, в них после н и р пишется ь: день-деньской, июньский, сентябрьский, октябрьский, ноябрьский, декабрьский.